# Parallel Function Execution in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a costly function that I'm using in a query that I'd like to be executed in parallel, but postgres doesn't seem to want to do so.

Basically, just doing:

```
SELECT expensive_func(a, b, c) FROM table;
```

Is it not possible to get this to utilize parallel sequential scanning? Or is there a configuration preventing me from doing so?

The function is marked as parallel safe and max parallel workers per gather is set appropriately.

This is Postgres 9.6.3

Function declaration:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expensive_func(args...)
    RETURNS result
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    STABLE
    PARALLEL SAFE
    AS $$
```

Comment: Do you get a parallel scan with `SELECT * FROM "table"`? Can you show the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement (the exact body is not important)?

Comment: `show dynamic_shared_memory_type`?..

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe just added the function declaration. I don't get a parallel scan with just a select. I've read that a where clause is required for parallel scan to be considered. I DO get a parallel scan with select statements that have where clauses. But is there no way to tell postgres to use parallel scan to parallelize an expensive function without a where clause?

Comment: @VaoTsun dynamic_shared_memory_type is posix

Comment: If the whole table is scanned, each row incurs a cost of `parallel_tuple_cost` (default 0.1). Is a parallel plan chosen if you lower that setting? What if you `SET force_parallel_mode=on`? Is the actual duration lower with a parallel plan?